# How to animate activity without finishing previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

In my application I want to animate my activity from right to left. Till now I am try this :

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

and this working fine but my previous activity got finished. What I want to do the same animation without finishing previous activity.

while trying like this :

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

only newly started activity go into animation and previous activity does get any effect. How can I animate both activity without finishing the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Handler in this case!
Put time on Handler on First Activity. During this time animate your first activity. After this step handler give the control to your second activity and then you start animation on second activity

Answer (score 0):

I think that your animations might be the problem. I have the same effect using the following animation files:

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="-100%"
       android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```